# Why the promise doesn't work when outside of the loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to dynamically add fusionCharts into the AngularJS page. I'm loading charts data into model object, the charts object does display, but with "No data to display" content.

My app.js:

```
(function () {

var modelListOfCharts = ["1", "4", "5", "6"];
var model = {};
var app = angular.module('chartDash', ["ng-fusioncharts"]);

app.controller('fussionController',["$scope","DataService", function ($scope, DataService) {
    $scope.chartData = {};

    DataService.getThings().then(function () {
        $scope.myListOfCharts = modelListOfCharts;
        $scope.chartData = model;
    });
}]);

app.service("DataService", ["$http", "$timeout", "$q", function ($http, $timeout, $q) {
    return {
        getThings: function () {
            var dfd = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                angular.forEach(modelListOfCharts, function(chartId) {
                    $http.get('/FusionCharts/GetChartData/', { params: { chartID: chartId } }).success(function (result) {
                        model[chartId] = result;
                    });
                });
                dfd.resolve(model);
            }, 300);
            return dfd.promise;
        }
    };
}]);
})();
```

My html:

```
<div ng-controller="fussionController">
    <div ng-repeat="n in myListOfCharts">
        <h2>Chart number {{n}}</h2>
        <fusioncharts width="100%"
                      height="400"
                      type="MSCombi2D"
                      datasource="{{chartData[n]}}"></fusioncharts>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I put dfd.resolve(model); inside the loop it works but only displays data for one chart.

```
    app.service("DataService", ["$http", "$timeout", "$q", function ($http, $timeout, $q) {
    return {
        getThings: function () {
            var dfd = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function () {
                angular.forEach(modelListOfCharts, function(chartId) {
                    $http.get('/FusionCharts/GetChartData/', { params: { chartID: chartId } }).success(function (result) {
                        model[chartId] = result;
                        dfd.resolve(model);
                    });
                });

            }, 300);
            return dfd.promise;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Could you provide a plunker with your error ? Your way of using promises is really messy and i'd like to play a bit with it to provide you a clean solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are multiple http gets there will be multiple promises. So you have to wait for all those promises to be resolved. Try this.

```
app.service("DataService", ["$http", "$timeout", "$q", function ($http, $timeout, $q) {
    return {
        getThings: function () {
            var arrayOfPromises = [];
                angular.forEach(modelListOfCharts, function(chartId) {
                    arrayOfPromises.push($http.get('/FusionCharts/GetChartData/', { params: { chartID: chartId } }).success(function (result) {
                        model[chartId] = result;
                    }));
                 });

            return $q.all(arrayOfPromises);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: That looks good to me. Since you remove the $timeout that shouldn't be used 99% of the time ppl try.

Comment: amazing, been fighting with this for last few days, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a promise for each chart and then wait for them all to resolve:

```
app.service("DataService", ["$http", "$timeout", "$q",
  function($http, $timeout, $q) {
    return {
      getThings: function() {
        var promises;

        $timeout(function() {
          promises = modelListOfChart.map(function(chartId) {
            var dfd = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/FusionCharts/GetChartData/', {
              params: {
                chartID: chartId
              }
            }).success(function(result) {
              model[chartId] = result;
              dfd.resolve(model);
            });
            // Might want to add a reject for errors...

            return dfd;
          });
        }, 300);

        return $q.all(promises);
      }
    };
  }
]);
```